# Unnecessary IO and Product Join Indicators

Tags: teradata

what are Unnecessary-IO and Product Join Indicators in Teradata. How are these metrics determined for a query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Product Join Indicator** is the ratio of CPU Seconds to IO for a query. Generally when the PJI is greater than 3 the query should be reviewed. Greater than 6 you may find the query is performing an unnecessary product join. To calculate the PJI using DBQL metrics: `(AMPCPUTime * 1000) / TotalIOCount`

**Unnecessary IO Indicator** is the ratio of IO to CPU Seconds. If the UII is greater than 3 the query should be reviewed to eliminate full-table scans and possibly redistribution steps. UII is a reasonable indicator to identify queries that may benefit from additional statistics to indexing improvements. To calculate the UII using DBQL metrics: `TotalIOCount / (AMPCPUTime * 1000)`

Comment: Thanks Rob, what constitutes a IOCount?. is it a single data block read?

Comment: If I recall correctly, TotalIOCount in DBQL is the AMP Level IO necessary to process the query. It should be both table and spool related IO at a block level.